# How to use the IEEEtran style for \printbibliography

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, biber, ieeetran, ieee-style

I need to comply with a certain paper template,

```
\documentclass[conference]{IEEEtran}
% I do not know what the command below does but it was present in the template file.
\def\BibTeX{{\rm B\kern-.05em{\sc i\kern-.025em b}\kern-.08em
        T\kern-.1667em\lower.7ex\hbox{E}\kern-.125emX}} 

\begin{document}
Content with citation \cite{key}
\begin{thebibliography}{00}
    \bibitem{key} Manual citation text
\end{thebibliography}
```

However, I have used a more automated approach with a separate bibliography file,

```
\documentclass[conference]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage[backend=biber,sorting=none,style=ieee,url=false]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{resource.bib}

\begin{document}
Content with citation \cite{key}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

This works well, except that the formatting is completely different (much larger text, different margins). How can I apply the style used in the `thebibliography` environment to the `\printbibliography` command?

Comment: Pretty much a duplicate of https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/386709/35864 (I should have searched for a duplicate before I wrote the answer), but the answer here is more detailed.

Comment: Maybe a reverse dupe might be more appropriate given that the answer here now covers everything the other answer mentions?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you are submitting a paper to IEEE transactions, journals or proceedings, you should not be using `biblatex` (and its `\printbibliography` command) at all.

The [`IEEEtran`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/ieeetran) package comes with several BibTeX styles that you can use if you want to generate your bibliography from `.bib` files. The [package documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/IEEEtran/IEEEtran_HOWTO.pdf) explains

> Bibliographies  are  most  easily  (and  correctly)  generated using  the  `IEEEtran`  BibTeX package  [[`IEEEtran` BibTeX package documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/IEEEtran/bibtex/IEEEtran_bst_HOWTO.pdf)]  which  is  easily invoked via
>
> ```
> \bibliographystyle{IEEEtran}
> \bibliography{IEEEabrv,mybibfile}
> ```

A document for IEEE submission might look like this

```
\documentclass[conference]{IEEEtran}

\begin{document}
Content with citation \cite{IEEEexample:articlelargepages}

\bibliographystyle{IEEEtran}
\bibliography{IEEEabrv,IEEEexample}
\end{document}
```

Note that it is recommended to replace the line `\bibliography{IEEEabrv,IEEEexample}` with the copy-and-pasted contents of the `.bbl` file for submission.

[image: IEEE bibliography]

---

Note also what the author of `biblatex-ieee` has to say about the aim of his project in https://github.com/josephwright/biblatex-ieee/pull/22

> [`biblatex-ieee`] should *never* be used with `IEEEtrans`. The latter has an official BibTeX style which (like all journal-type submissions) must be used as specified by the publisher. The `biblatex-ieee` bundle is for users of `biblatex` who want an IEEE (like) bibliography style. The most obvious use case to me is theses, though grant proposals, book chapters, etc. would also fall into the same potential spectrum.

That is, incidentally, one of the reasons why `biblatex-ieee` does not change the font size for the references, see also https://github.com/josephwright/biblatex-ieee/issues/37 and https://github.com/josephwright/biblatex-ieee/issues/49. `biblatex-ieee` only emulates the bibliography style (in the sense of presentation of bibliography information) and not the exact typography of the bibliography.

If you still want to use `biblatex-ieee` and want to emulate the typography of the bibliography more closely, you will want to change `\bibfont` as well as `\biblabelsep` and `\bibitemsep`.

```
\documentclass[conference]{IEEEtran}

\usepackage[backend=biber, style=ieee, url=false]{biblatex}

\renewcommand*{\bibfont}{\footnotesize}
\setlength{\biblabelsep}{\labelsep}
\setlength{\bibitemsep}{\IEEEbibitemsep}

\addbibresource{IEEEexample.bib}

\begin{document}
Content with citation \cite{IEEEexample:articlelargepages}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: IEEE-like bibliography with <code>biblatex</code>]

---

**Technical addendum**

The typographic formatting of the bibliography is usually controlled by the document class via the implementation of `thebibliography`. Since BibTeX generally produces a `thebibliography` environment, both manually generated bibliographies as well as BibTeX-generated bibliographies will have the same typographic style.

`biblatex`, on the other hand, has a completely different way of typesetting the bibliography and does not use `thebibliography` at all. That means that `IEEEtran`'s typographic bibliography settings are not automatically applied to `biblatex`-generated bibliographies.