# Biblatex with ieee doesn't produce the same output as bibtex with the ieeetran.bst configuration

Tags: ieeetran, ieee-style

I want to use biblatex with the biber backend for my ieeetran paper. When I use the following commands:

```
\documentclass[conference]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage[backend=biber, sorting=none, style=ieee, doi=false, isbn=false, url=false]{biblatex}
\bibliography{biblio}

\begin{document}
Abstract \cite{ibrahim_synchronous_2015}
\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

The references look like follows:
[image]

When I use the original

```
\documentclass[conference]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{cite}
\begin{document}
Abstract \cite{ibrahim_synchronous_2015}

\bibliographystyle{ieeetran} % use IEEEtran.bst style
\bibliography{IEEEabrv,biblio}

\end{document}
```

it looks like follows on the other hand:
[image]

You can see, that the version with biblatex is much mor spacious than the original one (second one). Are there any settings or other templates which make the references really look like the IEEEtran.bst style? The reason why I'm asking is, that I'm usally used to biblatex (with biber backend) and I don't always want to change the settings when I change between my documents.

Comment: I recall posting a similar question. Let me find it ;)

Comment: here it is: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/386709/proper-usage-of-biblatex-ieee-biblatex-style-in-an-ieeetran-document (with answer!)
Be advised that I'll mark this as duplicate.
Will you let me borrow your images to add more visual clues to my original question?

Comment: Thanks for the fast help. Yes, it solved the problem and looks better now. I can live with the small differences. And yes, you can use my pictures :)