# How to change space between numbers and entries in BibLaTeX using style=ieee

Tags: biblatex, ieee-style, ieeeconf

After I switched from using BibTeX to using BibLaTeX with the [IEEE style](https://github.com/josephwright/biblatex-ieee), my advisor complained that there is too much space between the entry number and entry content in the bibliography. How can I change that spacing?

The spacing below "References" is also different, so I'd also like to adjust that spacing.

**BibTeX Bibliography**
[image: screenshot of BibTeX Bibliography]

**BibLaTeX Bibliography**
[image: screenshot of BibLaTeX Bibliography]

This bibliography is for an IEEE conference paper, so I'm using a copy of `ieeeconf.cls` that I've mirrored [here](https://github.com/pwintz/hsl_templates/blob/main/ieeeconf.cls).
My BibLaTeX import line is

```
\usepackage[url = false,doi = false,isbn = false,natbib,style=ieee]{biblatex}
```

and I've reduced the size of the text to `\small` (per [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/386709/153678)) using

```
\renewcommand*{\bibfont}{\normalfont\small}
\printbibliography
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The spacing is determined by the length `\biblabelsep`, so set this to a value that suits your advisor.

Full example (using `article` class, since class is irrelevant to the problem).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[style=ieee]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}
\setlength{\biblabelsep}{.5em}
\begin{document}
\cite{chiu,aksin,cotton}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: output of code]

Comment: What defines the space to the left "[1]"? Also, where is the default value of `\biblabelsep` defined? It doesn't seem to be in the `ieeeconf` class nor in the `ieee` BibLaTeX style.

Comment: @PaulWintz `\biblabelsep` is a standard `biblatex` length used by any numeric or alpha styles, documented in the main `biblatex` documentation.  The bibliography is set as a list, so it is aligned to the left margin. To change that margin you would need to redefine the `bibliography` environment and set the left margin of the list accordingly.

Comment: Got it. I just found the full list of BibLaTeX lengths in "3.12.4 Lengths and Counters" of the BibLaTeX reference document at https://www.ctan.org/pkg/biblatex.